Win32_TSLicenseReport not generating report when AD has Japanese usernames
$fileName = (Invoke-WmiMethod Win32_TSLicenseReport -Name GenerateReportEx).FileName
$fileEntries = (Get-WmiObject Win32_TSLicenseReport | Where-Object FileName -eq $fileName).FetchReportEntries(0, 0).ReportEntries

These commands succeed when I have ONLY usernames in english alphabets. The moment I add a username in Japanese language, the $fileEntries comes out as empty. When I manually generate report and save it, I cannot see the entry of usernames saved in Japanese language. This definitely seems like an encoding issue. How to get past this?
